# Unable to click a label programatically with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, onclick, click, label

I have a js problem.  This site: http://befwifi.bobevans.com/Mobile.aspx (not my site)

How can you simulate a click on the “I AGREE TO THE TERMS” label with js programmatically?

The simulated click must do exactly what a real click does. ie Make the box look checked, without refreshing the page.

For example none of these work!

document.getElementsByTagName("label")[0].click()

$(document.getElementsByTagName("label")[0]).click()

$(document.getElementsByTagName("label")[0]).trigger("click")

(Site uses jquery)

Purpose:

I am creating a generic js script to record all clicks and inputs on a page. You can then replay those events when you land on the page again. I got stumped by this page because although i can easily record the onclick to the label, when i replay the click() programmatically it doesn't do the same as when i click on the element myself.

Comment: try $(document.getElementsByTagName("label:eq(1)").trigger("click")

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking the `checkbox` instead of the label. This will do what you want.

`document.getElementById("chkAcceptTerms").click();`

Comment: Unfortunately that results in the page reloading, which doesn't happen when you click it manually. I guess the real question is: Why doesn't $("label").click() or $("label").trigger("click") or document.getElementsByTagName("label")[0].click() or anything actually do exactly what happens when you manually click the label.

Answer (score 0):

You need to raise click on the related input, e.g. with an ID selector;

```
$("#" + $("label").attr("for")).click();
```

Comment: Unfortunately that also results in the page reloading, which doesn't happen when you click it manually. I guess the real question is: Why doesn't $("label").click() or $("label").trigger("click") or document.getElementsByTagName("label")[0].click() or anything actually do exactly what happens when you manually click the label.

Answer (score 0):

the webpage uses jquery mobile

`<input id="chkAcceptTerms" type="checkbox" name="chkAcceptTerms"/>
   <label for="chkAcceptTerms">I AGREE TO THE TERMS</label>`

to simulate click event try this:

```
$("#chkAcceptTerms").click();
```

Comment: Unfortunately that also results in the page reloading, which doesn't happen when you click it manually. I guess the real question is: Why doesn't $("label").click() or $("label").trigger("click") or document.getElementsByTagName("label")[0].click() or anything actually do exactly what happens when you manually click the label.